Stumped on demodulation, using python simulation end to end example of modulating a BPSK signal and demodulation but getting ~50% bit error
Can someone spot my mistake here:
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig
import komm

def mueller_muller(samples, sps, mu = 0):
    """
    clock sync
    """
    out = np.zeros(len(samples) + 10, dtype=np.complex64)
    out_rail = np.zeros(len(samples) + 10, dtype=np.complex64) # stores values, each iteration we need the previous 2 values plus current value
    i_in = 0 # input samples index
    i_out = 2 # output index (let first two outputs be 0)
    while i_out < len(samples) and i_in+16 < len(samples):
        out[i_out] = samples[i_in + int(mu)] # grab what we think is the "best" sample
        out_rail[i_out] = int(np.real(out[i_out]) > 0) + 1j*int(np.imag(out[i_out]) > 0)
        x = (out_rail[i_out] - out_rail[i_out-2]) * np.conj(out[i_out-1])
        y = (out[i_out] - out[i_out-2]) * np.conj(out_rail[i_out-1])
        mm_val = np.real(y - x)
        mu += sps + 0.3*mm_val
        i_in += int(np.floor(mu)) # round down to nearest int since we are using it as an index
        mu = mu - np.floor(mu) # remove the integer part of mu
        i_out += 1 # increment output index
    out = out[2:i_out] # remove the first two, and anything after i_out (that was never filled out)
    return out

def costas(samples, phase=0, freq=0):
    """
    freq
    """
    N = len(samples)
    # These next two params is what to adjust, to make the feedback loop faster or slower (which impacts stability)
    alpha = 0.132
    beta = 0.00932
    out = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.complex64)
    freq_log = []
    for i in range(N):
        out[i] = samples[i] * np.exp(-1j*phase) # adjust the input sample by the inverse of the estimated phase offset
        error = np.real(out[i]) * np.imag(out[i]) # This is the error formula for 2nd order Costas Loop (e.g. for BPSK)

        # Advance the loop (recalc phase and freq offset)
        freq += (beta * error)
        freq_log.append(freq * fs / (2*np.pi)) # convert from angular velocity to Hz for logging
        phase += freq + (alpha * error)

        # Optional: Adjust phase so its always between 0 and 2pi, recall that phase wraps around every 2pi
        while phase >= 2*np.pi:
            phase -= 2*np.pi
        while phase < 0:
            phase += 2*np.pi
    return out


def rrcosfilter(N, alpha, Ts, Fs):
    """
    Generates a root raised cosine (RRC) filter (FIR) impulse response.
    Parameters
    ----------
    N : int
        Length of the filter in samples.
    alpha : float
        Roll off factor (Valid values are [0, 1]).
    Ts : float
        Symbol period in seconds.
    Fs : float
        Sampling Rate in Hz.
    Returns
    ---------
    time_idx : 1-D ndarray of floats
        Array containing the time indices, in seconds, for
        the impulse response.
    h_rrc : 1-D ndarray of floats
        Impulse response of the root raised cosine filter.
    """

    T_delta = 1/float(Fs)
    time_idx = ((np.arange(N)-N/2))*T_delta
    sample_num = np.arange(N)
    h_rrc = np.zeros(N, dtype=float)

    for x in sample_num:
        t = (x-N/2)*T_delta
        if t == 0.0:
            h_rrc[x] = 1.0 - alpha + (4*alpha/np.pi)
        elif alpha != 0 and t == Ts/(4*alpha):
            h_rrc[x] = (alpha/np.sqrt(2))*(((1+2/np.pi)* \
                    (np.sin(np.pi/(4*alpha)))) + ((1-2/np.pi)*(np.cos(np.pi/(4*alpha)))))
        elif alpha != 0 and t == -Ts/(4*alpha):
            h_rrc[x] = (alpha/np.sqrt(2))*(((1+2/np.pi)* \
                    (np.sin(np.pi/(4*alpha)))) + ((1-2/np.pi)*(np.cos(np.pi/(4*alpha)))))
        else:
            h_rrc[x] = (np.sin(np.pi*t*(1-alpha)/Ts) +  \
                    4*alpha*(t/Ts)*np.cos(np.pi*t*(1+alpha)/Ts))/ \
                    (np.pi*t*(1-(4*alpha*t/Ts)*(4*alpha*t/Ts))/Ts)

    return time_idx, h_rrc

def plot_constellation(signal, title):
    real = signal.real
    imag = signal.imag
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.scatter(real, imag)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel('real')
    plt.ylabel('imag')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
    

# generate a signal with a specified modulation type and see if we can remove part of just that one.
def get_psd(signal, sampling_rate):
    """ This function gets the power spectral density from the signal using Welch's function. """
    freq, Pxx = welch(signal, fs = sampling_rate)
    sorted_indices = np.argsort(freq)
    freq = freq[sorted_indices]
    Pxx = Pxx[sorted_indices]
    Pxx = np.log(Pxx)
    return freq, Pxx

def plot_psd(f,pxx,title):
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.plot(f, pxx)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel('freq hz')
    plt.ylabel('power')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

bpsk_modem = komm.PSKModulation(2)
# create BPSK signal
# Generate random bit stream
# rate = 1
bits = np.random.randint(0, 2, 256)
baseband = bpsk_modem.modulate(bits)
plot_constellation(baseband, "base modulated signal")


# zero insert upsample (10 samples per symbol)
rate = 10
baseband_upsampled = np.zeros(len(baseband) * rate, dtype='complex')
baseband_upsampled[::rate] = baseband
plot_constellation(baseband_upsampled, "baseband_upsampled modulated signal")


# pulse shaping filter (root raised cosine filter)
pulse = komm.RootRaisedCosinePulse(rolloff=0.25, length_in_symbols=16)
n = np.linspace(-8, 8, 16 * rate)
psf_coeff = pulse.impulse_response(n)
baseband_shaped = sig.lfilter(psf_coeff, np.sum(psf_coeff), baseband_upsampled)
plot_constellation(baseband_shaped, "baseband_shaped modulated signal")

# welch psd at baseband
faxis, psd_baseband = sig.welch(baseband_shaped, nperseg=2**12, return_onesided=False)
plot_psd(faxis, psd_baseband, "baseband")

print(baseband_shaped.shape)
# Matched filtering with root raised cosine filter
matched_filter_output = sig.lfilter(psf_coeff, 1.0, baseband_shaped)

plot_constellation(matched_filter_output, "matched_filter_output modulated signal")

# t,rrc_impulse_response = rrcosfilter(64,.25,16,rate)
# apply pulse shaping
# filtered_signal = np.convolve(baseband_shaped, rrc_impulse_response)
print(matched_filter_output.shape)


# clock recovery technique
# Downsample 
time_sync_signal = mueller_muller(matched_filter_output,rate)
# print(time_sync_signal.shape)
# time_sync_signal = matched_filter_output[::rate]
plot_constellation(time_sync_signal, "time_sync_signal modulated signal")


carrier_recovery = costas(time_sync_signal)


plot_constellation(carrier_recovery, "carrier_recovery modulated signal")

demodulated_bits = bpsk_modem.demodulate(time_sync_signal[:256])

# Differential decoding, so that it doesn't matter whether our BPSK was 180 degrees rotated without us realizing it
# demodulated_bits = (demodulated_bits[1:] - demodulated_bits[0:-1]) % 2
# # demodulated_bits = demodulated_bits.astype(np.uint8) # for decoder
# plot_constellation(demodulated_bits, "diff decoded modulated signal")
print(baseband.shape, demodulated_bits.shape)

ber = np.sum(bits[:len(demodulated_bits)] != demodulated_bits) / len(bits)
print(f'Bit Error Rate (BER): {ber}')

```

